# After logging into site with Mechanize, follow a non-relative link

Tags: python, cookies, mechanize

I've successfully logged into a site but then rather follow links I'd rather just tell Mechanize to go to a page within the same site.

```
# let's open a site
r = br.open('https://www.example.com')

# select the login form
br.select_form(nr=0)

# enter user name and password and submit
br.form['user']="admin"
br.form['pass']="1234"
br.submit()

# read the data
html = br.response().read()

# change address
br.open('http://www.example.com/a_page_without_a_link_to_it')
html = br.response().read()
```

The problem seems to be that open() resets the cookies so I'm no longer logged in.

Not sure what I'm missing. I've looked at follow_link() but oviously I need to follow a link lol.

Is there a function similar to br.goto('/a_page_without_a_link_to_it') that will preserve the login cookies?

Comment: Not sure if this will make a difference, but I don't think you need to use `response()`.  Try `result = br.open(...)` followed by `html = result.read()`